# Persist app when terminate using UserDefaults

Tags: ios, swift, persistence, nsuserdefaults

I want to save image using userdefaults, what I want to achieve is after image being change and the app terminate it. the image user change is still there. how do I achieve this with userdefaults.

This is my code when user pick image and save it in userdefaults

```
var data: Data? //I make a reference data to save imageData in pickerController
@objc func handleImagePicker() {
    let imagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()
    imagePickerController.allowsEditing = true
    imagePickerController.sourceType = .photoLibrary
    imagePickerController.delegate = self

    present(imagePickerController, animated: true)
}

@objc func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
    if let editedImage = info[.editedImage] as? UIImage {
        guard let imageData = editedImage.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.5) else { return }
        self.data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: imageData)
        UserDefaults.standard.set(data, forKey: "profileImageEditedKey")
        UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
        profileImageView.image = editedImage.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
    } else if let originalImage = info[.originalImage] as? UIImage {
        guard let imageData = originalImage.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1) else { return }
        self.data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: imageData)
        UserDefaults.standard.set(data, forKey: "profileImageOriginalKey")
        UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
        profileImageView.image = originalImage.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
    }
    dismiss(animated: true)
}
```

This is the code I place in viewWillAppear when I fetch the data after the app terminate

```
private func fetchData() {
    guard let data = data else { return }
    guard let image = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: data) as? UIImage else { return }

    profileImageView.image = image.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
    print("fetch...")
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. it is not a good idea to save big data in `userdefaults`,  it is often not recommended as it is not the most efficient way to save images; a more efficient way is to save your image in the application's Documents Directory. you use `Data` `write` func to do that.
   there are other third library too.
2. if you insist using `UserDefaults`

   to save image

   ```
   guard let imageData = editedImage.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.5) else { return }
   UserDefaults.standard.set(imageData, forKey: "profileImageEditedKey")
   UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
   ```

   to get image from `UserDefaults`

   ```
   guard let data = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "profileImageOriginalKey") as? Data else {
       return;
   }
   let image = UIImage.init(data: data);
   ```

Comment: I know I'm not suppose store image in userdefaults, I'm still new to iOS, so that's why I only use userdefaults. but hey your solution when I try to terminate, the picture I change is still not there. did I put it wrong? I put the get image in fetch function

Comment: in your func `fetchData`, when did you `init` your `data`, first you make sure the data your saved exist, print some log for that or debug that step by step to find.

Comment: sorry I missed the **UIImage.init** it work perfectly :) thank you